# How to detect when a user has been logged out automatically by the deletion of its session?

Tags: php, laravel

I would know how to detect if a user has been logged out automatically by Laravel.

If a user is not logged in with the `remember_token` Session will be erased after a while.
But how to detect when the session is gone  ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't detect WHEN. You can detect WHETHER it's gone.

Comment: Ok but what if I want to know if a user has been logged out automatically to show it to the other users ?
I only can handle the manual logout event..

Comment: There is no process (built-in by default) that runs through sessions, matches them with your users and queries your users' browser to tell you whether something happened. The way it works is by user sending a request to you, they include a session cookie, PHP finds a session file associated with it. Then if all is good, they are logged in, otherwise not. There exists no event mechanism to notify you or anyone else about WHEN session is invalid. To know that, you need user interaction.